# How to interpret VStack{ .. } from SwiftUI's official tutorial code?

Tags: swift, swiftui

In the following code, I know

1. `body` is a computed property which only have a `get` part.
2. `return` is omitted for `VStack`

but what's `{ .. }` after Vstack? is this Initialization or closures?
and what's inside {}, nothing return i think.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            MapView()
                .frame(height: 300)

            CircleImage()
                .offset(y: -130)
                .padding(.bottom, -130)

            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text("Turtle Rock")
                    .font(.title)
                HStack(alignment: .top) {
                    Text("Joshua Tree National Park")
                        .font(.subheadline)
                    Spacer()
                    Text("California")
                        .font(.subheadline)
                }
            }
            .padding()

            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `return` keyword for computed properties can now be omitted in swift 5.1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you look at the docs for [`VStack.init`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/vstack/3278367-init), you'll see that the last argument it accepts is indeed a closure. The magic here is that the closure is marked with `@ViewBuilder`.

`@ViewBuilder` is a kind of [*function builder*](https://blog.vihan.org/swift-function-builders/). The idea is that you pass in a closure containing a bunch of *expressions*, and then the function builder will combine those expressions into a single value. It's kind of like returning an array, but in an arguably better-looking syntax. (it's not really an array though. The return type of the closure is decided by the function builder.)

In your code, you are returning an "array" of 4 views.

1. `MapView`
2. `CircleImage`
3. another `VStack`
4. `Spacer`

These will get passed to the `ViewBuilder`, and it combines all of them into a single `View` object.

And if you are wondering what the methods called on at the end of each view are doing, they are just methods that return slight modifications of the objects on which they are called. For example `padding` returns the same view, but with some padding applied.

Comment: Thank you so much, this explains everything.

Answer (score 2):

When you look at the signature of `VStack` initializer:

```
public init(alignment: HorizontalAlignment = .center, spacing: CGFloat? = nil, @ViewBuilder content: () -> Content)
```

You can see that it takes 3 arguments, the first two have default values so they can be omitted (as in your example). The last one is a `ViewBuilder` and has no default value, so needs to be provided.

When you look at a definition of a `ViewBuilder` it takes between 0 and 10 Views:

```
static func buildBlock() -> EmptyView
static func buildBlock<Content>(Content) -> Content
static func buildBlock<C0, C1>(C0, C1) -> TupleView<(C0, C1)>
static func buildBlock<C0, C1, C2>(C0, C1, C2) -> TupleView<(C0, C1, C2)>
/....
static func buildBlock<C0, C1, C2, C3, C4, C5, C6, C7, C8, C9>(C0, C1, C2, C3, C4, C5, C6, C7, C8, C9) -> TupleView<(C0, C1, C2, C3, C4, C5, C6, C7, C8, C9)>
```

Long story short, what you see between { .. } is a `ViewBuilder`, which is a closure, that is part of  the initializer.

Comment: Thank you so much, this explains everything.

Answer (score 2):

The kind of `VStack` syntax is possible thanks to a new feature in Swift 5.1 called **Function Builder**.
Without function builders, the code would look like that:

```
var body: some View {
    var builder = VStackBuilder()
    builder.add(Image(uiImage: image))
    builder.add(Text(title))
    builder.add(Text(subtitle))
    return builder.build()
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this explains everything.